# How To Create A Custom Colorbar

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colorbar, contourf

I'm trying to customize a colorbar on a contoured image I am producing. I would like custom intervals with different colors between each interval. Below are a few lines of how I tried to generate such a colorbar but with no success.

```
contourfm(lats,lons,data,[0 25 50 75 125 150 200 300 400]);

c = colorbar;
c.Label.String = titl;
c.Limits = [minC 500];
c.Ticks = [0 25 50 75 125 150 200 300 400];

limits = c.Limits;
cInt = linspace(limits(1),limits(2),64);

cmap = flipud(jet);
```

Below is an example of how I am trying to make rainfall <25% of normal a yellow/orange color. I do similar iterations for 25-50% of normal, etc..

```
in1 =  find(cInt <= 25);
   nin1 = length(in1);

for i=1:nin1
    cmap(in1(i),:)      =  [1 0 0];     %[0.9937,0.7454,0.2403];
end
```

This code however is not getting me the desired results.

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Hey Daniel. The problem is simply that it's not working. I currently am having trouble developing a custom colorbar and the code above is getting warmer but not quite there yet.